# Factory class with abstractmethod

Tags: python, abstract-factory, abc

I've created a factory class called `FitFunction` that adds a whole bunch of stuff beyond what I've shown. The label method `pretty_string` is supposed to just return the string as written. When I run this file, it prints a string that is as useful as the `repr`. Does someone know how I would go about implementing this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import

import abc
import types
import numpy as np

class FitFunction(object):

    def __init__(self, python_function):

        assert isinstance(python_function, types.FunctionType)
        self._py_function = python_function

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def pretty_string():
        r"""
        Return some pretty string.
        """


class Gaussian(FitFunction):


    def __init__(self):

        def gaussian(x, mu, sigma, A):
            coeff = (_np.sqrt(2.0 * _np.pi) * sigma)**(-1.0)
            arg   = -.5 * (((x - mu) / sigma)**2.0)
            return A * coeff * _np.exp(arg)

        FitFunction.__init__(self, gaussian)

        @staticmethod
        def pretty_string():
            return "1D Gaussian"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Gaussian.pretty_string: %s" % Gaussian().pretty_string() )
```

I subclass `FitFunction` to create `Gaussian` because I apply `Gaussian` to many different data sets with the same parameters so that I can compare the output.

For reference, this is what happens when I execute the file:

```
me$ ./FitFunction_SO_test.py 
Gaussian.pretty_string: <bound method Gaussian.pretty_string of <__main__.Gaussian object at 0x1005e2f90>>
```

I'm looking for the following result:

```
me$ ./FitFunction_SO_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./FitFunction_SO_test.py", line 43, in <module>
    print("Gaussian.pretty_string: %s" % Gaussian().pretty_string())
TypeError: pretty_string() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Your indentation is not correct in the `Gaussian` class, so `pretty_string` is being defined as a local variable in the `__init__` method. Make sure the `@staticmethod` and `def` are lined up with the `def` for `__init__`, not the `def` for the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
print("Gaussian.pretty_string: %s" % Gaussian.pretty_string())
```

Or else you are printing the `repr` of the *method*, not the *result of calling the method*, which is the string you are looking for.

Comment: That just returns None. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @blalterman Huh? What returns `None`? It prints `None`? It's working for me. It prints `Gaussian.pretty_string: 1D Gaussian` on Python 2.7.12.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will fix your problem since I cannot check it myself right now but you should probably be using `@abc.abstractstaticmethod` (and get rid of the `self` argument obviously) to decorate the base class method. If that doesn't fix it I'll delete this answer later. If it does fix it I'll edit this into a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I needed to get rid of `self`. But that's only part of the problem. See the edits.

Comment: Still pretty sure you need to be using `@abstractstaticmethod` instead of `@abstractmethod`. Have you tried that?

Comment: `abstractstaticmethod` isn't present in my version of `abc`. It's probably worth noting that I'm on python 2.7.

Comment: Ah ha. Gotcha. I'm unlikely to be much help then. Much luck.